# Trying to get my website url not to show in address bar

Tags: javascript

I have 4 simple extensions that every new tab my website opens. I am trying to get it to not show my url in the address bar. Any help in doing it for 1 or all 4 would be greatly appreciated.

Chrome Extension:

```js
chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(
 function(tab){
  var newTabURL = {url: 'https://www.mywebsite.com'};
  
  if(tab.url === "chrome://newtab/")
  {
   chrome.tabs.update(newTabURL);
  }
  
  console.log(tab.url);
 }

);
```

Firefox Extension:

```js
browser.tabs.onCreated.addListener(
 function(tab){
  var newTabURL = {url: 'https://www.mywebsite.com'};
  
  if(tab.url === "about:newtab")
  {
   browser.tabs.update(newTabURL);
  }
  
  console.log(tab.url);
 }
);
```

Opera Extension:

```js
chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(
 function(tab){
  var newTabURL = {url: 'https://www.mywebsite.com'};
  
  if(tab.url === "chrome://startpage/")
  {
   chrome.tabs.update(newTabURL);
  }
  
  console.log(tab.url);
 }
);
```

Edge Extension:

```js
browser.tabs.onCreated.addListener(
 function(tab){
  var newTabURL = {url: 'https://www.mywebsite.com'};
  browser.tabs.update(newTabURL);
  console.log(tab.url);
 }
);
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible. I also don't understand why you would not want users to know the address of the site they are on. Sounds a little shady to me.

Comment: Not shady. I just dont have the money to get extensions made. So i made these when you still download from the browsers. But extensions do not have a url so i thought if there was a way to get mine to do that great.